# How do I use a Mapping-Level Parameter as an input to an SQL Transformation?

Tags: parameters, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

How do I use a mapping-level parameter as an input to an SQL Transformation?  I tried two different approaches that are not working for me:

---

First Try:

1. I put together a "dummy table" that is a relational data object which returns one row with one column using this SQL `select 'dummy' as Dummy`.
2. I connected the Dummy column to the input of my SQL transformation.
3. I set the SQL Query of the SQL transformation to this `?RETURN_VALUE? = call dbo.MySproc ($MyParameter)`

When I try this and check the data viewer, I get an error that says `Cannot parse parameter [$MyParameter], because the value is not valid`.  I tried variations of $MyParameter, $$MyParameter, and MyParameter, all based on what I've seen in the documentation, but I get an SQL error regardless.

Here is what this all looks like:

[image: First Attempt]

---

Second Try:

1. I use the same dummy table from step #1 above
2. I put in an expression transformation that takes the dummy input and has an output that I tried to set to my mapping-level parameter.  The output expression I used is `$MyParam`
3. I connected the output of the expression transformation to the input of the SQL transformation.

When I try this, I get a validation error involving the expression transformation that says `Error: <<PM Parse Error>> invalid token ... $<<<<MyParameter`.  Again I tried some variations of parameter syntax that I've seen in the documentation but I get the same error everytime.

Here is what my second try looks like:

[image: Second Attempt]

---

Here is how I declared my mapping-level parameter:

[image: Mapping-Level Parameter Declaration]

Edit 1: I found this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060716/using-mapping-parameter-in-an-informatica-stored-procedure-call?rq=1) that mentions that I should set the `IsExprVar` field of the mapping parameter to `FALSE`.  I must have a different version of PowerCenter because I don't see an `IsExprVar` field anywhere and I don't get any results when I search the help files for that term.

Edit 2: I included my mapping-level parameter declaration

Comment: @MarekGrzenkowicz I had no idea there was a difference.  Is there a trial version of Informatica PowerCenter Designer?  I found what I have here https://community.informatica.com/solutions/pcexpress even though it has "PowerCenter" in the title.

Comment: Right, I forgot about PowerCenter Express - it is based on Informatica Developer. There was a [trick that allowed to download Designer as a part of some Oracle BI package](http://www.disoln.org/2012/09/Informatica-PowerCenter-9-Installation-and-Configuration-Complete-Guide.html), although I'm not sure if it still works.

Answer (score -2):

Here's what you need to do:

1.Declare the mapping parameter as $$MyParameter(keep the Is Expression Variable option as false while declaring the parameter), single $ is for Informatica inbuilt parameters.

2.In an Expression create a port MyPort and in the expression set it to $$ MyParameter.

3.Drag the same port in your SQL Transformation, and in the SQL query refer to it as : ~MyPort~ not the actual parameter.

Comment: This will not work. OP is using PowerCenter Express, not PowerCenter Designer.